# Couldn't get Spring XD field-value-counter of a json string that is sent through RabbitMQ

Tags: json, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-xd

I'm trying to build a Spring XD stream that takes a field-value-counter of a json string.
Json string is sent in a message through RabbitMQ queue with header Content-Type of application/json.
Spring XD logs the message(Json string) and writes it to a file but it doesn't return a field-value-counter nor shows it on the list in spring xd shell (xd:>field-value-counter list).

Here's my shell commands

```
stream create rabbitqueue1 --definition "rabbit | log"

stream create rabbitqueue1jsonset1 --definition "tap:stream:rabbitqueue1 > field-value-counter --fieldName=type --name=proftype" --deploy

stream create rabbitqueue1out --definition "tap:stream:rabbitqueue1 > file --binary=true --name=rabbitqueue1outfile" --deploy

stream deploy rabbitqueue1
```

Here's an example json string

```
{
"created": "2017-01-18T09:45:34.716+05:30",
"firstName": "FirstName",
"id": 1,
"lastName": "LastName",
"profileName": "Profname",
"type": "admin"
 }
```

The question is why Spring XD stream doesn't count field values of the json string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FVC can only handle `Tuple` or `String` payloads (or a java bean).

The Rabbit source produces a `byte[]` by default unless the content-type is `text/plain`.

If you add `--inputType=text/plain` to the `field-value-counter`, the message bus will convert the `byte[]` to `String`.